# Getting 401 from Resttemplate but getting response from Chrome

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

i have a service call which give me a JSON response with some data in it . One of the field in JSON is a URL . This URL can be used to call another service which is GET call. The URL have 3 query params and no seperate authentication is required as per guideline because from the parent call, provider will give a token will be valid for sometime and its passing in URL.

```
URL : https://ep9.abc/v2/media/files/b9fe8e90? 
      tokencreator=BFS&tokenexpires=1656712486&token=w8P3mbv

tokencreator: BFS
tokenexpires: 1656712486
token: w8P3mbv
```

When i simply click on above URL it download all required files in chrome.
But when i try to call it in Spring using Resttemplate its giving me 401.

My First service call (To get this URL) is using OAuth 2.0.

When i see the Browser Network tab below are the details i am seeing .

```
 Request URL: https://ep9.abc/v2/media/files/b9fe8e90? 
 tokencreator=BFS&tokenexpires=1656712486&token=w8P3mbv
 Request Method: GET
 Status Code: 200 OK
 Remote Address: 199.888.888.888:443
 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

 Accept:  html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8, 
 application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
 Connection: keep-alive
 Host: ep9.abc
 sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
 sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
 sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
 Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
 Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
 Sec-Fetch-Site: none
 Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Below is the code i am trying to call resttemplate , i tried to extract the query params and tried to send it explicitly but still its saying 401.

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("tokencreator", tokencreator);
 params.put("tokenexpires", tokenexpires);
 params.put("token", token);

 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
 HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

 ResponseEntity<byte[]> zipFiles = 
 restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl,HttpMethod.GET,entity,byte[].class,params);
```

please help me to fix this.

Comment: Its working when i changed from Resttemplate to HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you should send a request in which you send token, tokencreator and tokenexpires as query parameters.

The code you wrote does not add those query parameters to base url. In order for it to work, you can send query parameters using following code:

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
            HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    
            // Query parameters
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl)
                    // Add query parameter
                    .queryParam("tokencreator", tokencreator)
                    .queryParam("tokenexpires", tokenexpires)
                    .queryParam("token", token);
    
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> zipFiles =
                    restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET,entity,byte[].class);
```

Comment: I tried it but no luck . Even i tried to hardcode the URL in exchange method like "files/b9fe8e90?tokencreator=BFS&tokenexpires=1656712486&token=w8P3mbv"  But still it fails 401 . If i simply paste it in Chrome its gives me zip file

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code. I've noticed that the token is sent in the header and as a query parameter, which is quite strange. Are you sure it should be like that?

Comment: Yes , if i just past it in Chrome it’s downloading the files . Couldn’t understand what is the mistake in code.

Comment: Can you post error message you getting?

Comment: Anything todo with http or https

Comment: 401 . Unauthorized. Need to pass a valid token to access files.

Answer (score 0):

Its working when i changed from Resttemplate to HttpURLConnection